# ipa failed to install in itunes 11

Tags: itunes, xcode4.5, iphone-5, xcode3.2

I have tried this so far but still no luck my app is not installing onto some devices.

Here are the steps.

1. Added UDID of 3 devices (2 X iPhone 5, iPad 4).
2. Modified Development Provisioning Profile (Using * APP ID).
3. Deleted Old Provisioning Profiles from Xcode and clicked refresh xcode downloaded profiles.
4. Signed the app and created .ipa and sent to client who is having iphone 5.
5. App failed to install.

Even tried manually downloading of provisioning profile but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Facing the same issue, Banging my head since a week. When I try to add from iTunes to my iPad it works. Also It worked by manually adding the provisioning profile with my device, but not at client device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today.  I've been able to install on devices connected to my computer just fine, but when I tried to send the .ipa file and Ad Hoc distribution profile to a tester, he was not able to install it via itunes.  He just received an error saying "ITunes Sync: 'appName' failed to install."

It turns out that I had signed the distribution package .ipa file with a different provisioning profile than the Ad Hoc one that I had sent to the tester.  That happened because I had just made the Ad Hoc one and it wasn't in XCode yet.

Here are the steps I needed to fix it:

1) Before building app, I went to Devices in Organizer

2) Clicked on Provisioning Profiles on left, just under Library

3) Click Refresh at bottom right so that it copies all provisioning profiles from your Apple Developer account into XCode

4) Close Organizer and go to Product/Archive to build app as Archive

5) Go back to Organizer and click on Archives.  New archive should be in list

6) Highlight new Archive and click Distribute

7) Choose "Save for Enterprise or Ad Hoc deployment

8) In next step, be sure to choose your Ad Hoc profile

9) Save the .iap archive file

10) Download your Ad Hoc provisioning profile Provisioning Profiles section of your Apple Developer account and send that file and the .ipa file to your tester

This also assumes that you have added your tester's device to your Ad Hoc profile